# How to get a stackpanel to overflow into another?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, stackpanel

I'm trying to get a stackpanel to overflow on another one when elements don't have enough space left. For the moment I've just got two basic stackpanels: `stackpanel` with all my elements in to start with, and `overflow`, where the elements are moved to when they can't fit in `stackpanel`. This is what I'm doing on `stackpanel`'s SizeChanged event:

```
        //Move each item from the overflow back to the stackpanel to measure them again
        foreach (var item in overflow.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
        {
            overflow.Children.Remove(item);
            stackpanel.Children.Insert(0, item);
        }
        foreach (var item in stackpanel.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
        {
            // measure the box around the child
            var _ItemBounds = item.TransformToVisual(null).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, item.ActualWidth, item.ActualHeight));
            // measure the grid containing the stackpanel
            var _Intersection = stackpanelgrid.TransformToVisual(null).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, stackpanelgrid.ActualWidth, stackpanelgrid.ActualHeight));
            _Intersection.Intersect(_ItemBounds);

            //If the item is partially or completely hidden:
            if (!_Intersection.Equals(_ItemBounds))
            {
                stackpanel.Children.Remove(item);
                overflow.Children.Insert(0, item);
            }
        }
```

My issue is that the items are correctly moved down to overflow, but they don't come back up. What's the problem?

Comment: have you considered using a WrapGrid? Or do you have a strong dependency on StackPanels

Comment: I can't really, as my second stackpanel isn't on the same horizontal axis. This is what it looks like (the first stackpanel is to the left of the poster, and the overflow is where the description is): http://i.imgsafe.org/c3ef209dcb.png

Comment: look into RelativePanel w/ Adaptive Triggers. I don't know enough about your requirements, so hacking stack panels might be the only way but I would look into all other options before that.

Comment: The problem is that the title, genres, and description of the movie/TV show can vary massively in length. For example, if the title is "E.T.", it doesn't need to wrap the description. But if it's "Dr. Strangelove or how I learned to stop worrying and love the bomb", it needs to wrap the description, the scores, and the genres, when it's on a small screen. The length is too unpredictable for me to use anything other than overflowing stack panels :/